# LogManager exists method in Log4j2 is not working

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

`LogManager.exists(loggerName)` method in Log4j2 is not working as it worked for log4j1. please advice the alternate method which does same task.

This is required  to log into default file if required logger is not available in xml

Answer (score 1):

This is the alternative I use:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
config.getLoggers().keySet().contains(loggerName);
```